# How to update file data stored in S3 bucket efficiently and inexpensively?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-athena

I am working on a project that is based on AWS services. In this project I upload large files containing thousands of records to `S3` bucket and I use `Athena` to query the data and creates reports. Recently I want to update data (let's say just a few records in a large file) and re-run reports with the new data!

What I have in mind is to load my data to a `Redshift Cluster` and run the updates on data persisted in Redshift and have a Lambda function to generate a new file using the updated data and replace the file in the S3 bucket. Is there a better way to accomplish this task?

Comment: you could use athena or glue or something else for your ETL??

Comment: If you are merely updating a few records, why not download the file and use a text editor? Or does it require recalculations that are best done via SQL? It might also be difficult to locate specific rows in many files. The real question is how many files would need to be processed to find the data and make the update. Feel free to Edit your question to provide more details.